# How to get the content between two specific lines in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript, search

How can I write a function to get the content between `mark 1` and `mark 2` for further processing? `mark` can be a string, or a function call, it doesn't matter.

```
mark 1

foo1
foo2
foo3

mark 2
```

Comment: Also asked at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40818999/660921

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [`:h getbufline()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getbufline%28%29):

> `getbufline({expr}, {lnum} [, {end}])`

> Return a List with the lines starting from {lnum} to {end}
> (inclusive) in the buffer {expr}.  If {end} is omitted, a
> List with only the line {lnum} is returned.

To get the line numbers you're looking for you can use `:search()` for example. See [`:h search()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#search%28%29).

For example in this file:

```
mark 1

foo1
foo2
foo3

mark 2
```

The command:

```
echo getbufline(bufnr('%'), 1, 7)
```

Will return the following list:

```
['mark 1', '', 'foo1', 'foo2', 'foo3', '', 'mark 2']
```

You might even want to wrap it in a function:

```
function! SearchForLines(pattern1, pattern2)
    let line1 = search(a:pattern1)
    let line2 = search(a:pattern2)

    return getbufline(bufnr('%'), line1, line2)
endfunction
```

This way to get the list of the lines between `mark 1` and `mark 2` you can simply do:

```
:echo SearchForLines('mark 1', 'mark 2')
```

**Edit** Note that as @Christian Brabandt noted in the comments, the function `getline()` can also be used and in some circumstances may be easier to use. See [`:h getline()`](https://vimhelp.org/builtin.txt.html#getline%28%29).

Comment: you can also just ust `getline()`

Comment: Absolutely I'll edit my answer :-)